# Manipulating series in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has a list of comma separated values in one column. I want to find the list of distinct entries, create a new column for each distinct entry in the dataframe, then fill the new columns with 1 or 0 depending on whether the row has the city name. 
The idea is to use the new columns in building a logistic regression model.
As an example

**Before**

```
Name    City 
Jack    NewYork,Chicago,Seattle
Jill    Seattle, SanFrancisco
Ted     Chicago,SanFrancisco
Bill    NewYork,Seattle
```

**After**

```
Name    NewYork     Chicago     Seattle     SanFrancisco
Jack    1           1           1           0
Jill    0           0           1           1
Ted     0           1           0           1
Bill    1           0           1           0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) `str` method:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Name": ["Jack", "Jill", "Ted", "Bill"],
     "City": ["NewYork,Chicago,Seattle", "Seattle,SanFrancisco", "Chicago,SanFrancisco", "NewYork,Seattle"]}
)

print(pd.concat((df, df.City.str.get_dummies(",")), axis=1))
```

Result:

```
   Name                     City  Chicago  NewYork  SanFrancisco  Seattle
0  Jack  NewYork,Chicago,Seattle        1        1             0        1
1  Jill     Seattle,SanFrancisco        0        0             1        1
2   Ted     Chicago,SanFrancisco        1        0             1        0
3  Bill          NewYork,Seattle        0        1             0        1
```